# Elements position inside div

Tags: html, css

How to position the long text and the button inside the div so that they are the full width of the page and the text is cut off and ends with ellipsis if it does not fit? **Only by changing the css file**

```
<div class="one">
    Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

I have tried smth like this

```
.one {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


button {
    float: right;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

Comment: i suggest to wrap your text in an `<p>` tag. texts inside an div witch also contains other elements are ugly atleast in my opinion

Comment: @Ifaruki the problem is that I can only change css file :(

Answer (score -1):

Try like this: Using display: flex will solve your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="one"> Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text
        <button>Button</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

.one {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 80px;
}

button {
    width: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't change the html file and add <span>